# How do I set a time interval to call data from a database? [Python]

Tags: python, database

I've tried searching for the answer to this but I'm new to coding so I think I may be searching the wrong areas. I'm trying to call a database and pull information at hourly intervals. This is the part of the script where I'm setting the time window and pulling the data.

```
    tZone = time.daylight 
    if tZone == 1:
        DateAdj = 4
    else:
        DateAdj = 5


    datasetI1path = "xxxxxxxxx"

    DateAdj = int(DateAdj)
    TimeAdj = float(DateAdj)
    TimeAdj *= 3600 #   Time adjustment in seconds.
    now = time.time() # Gives current time according to local TZ in seconds.
    now += TimeAdj # Adds above TimeAdj to current local TZ to match UTC.
    endTime = now - now % 3600 # This endTime function serves to set current time back to the nearest hour.
    endMin = endTime / 60
    startTime = endTime - 7 * 86400 #   Set start of time window to 7 days ago from nearest current hour.
    startTimeStr = time.strftime('%d%b%Y %H%M', time.localtime(startTime)) #    Return start time in DDMMYYYY format.
    endTimeStr = time.strftime('%d%b%Y %H%M', time.localtime(endTime)) #    Return end time in DDMMYYYY format.
    ValidTimeStr = endTimeStr
    abcTime = AbcTime()
    db = yyyy.open()
    db.setTimeWindow(startTimeStr, endTimeStr)
    db.timeZone = 'UTC'
    locTz = TimeZone.getTimeZone('US/Eastern')
    utcTz = TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC')

    #-------------------------------------------------------------#
    # DATASET I1                                                  #
    #-------------------------------------------------------------#

    tscI1 = TimeSeriesContainer()
    tscI1 = db.get(datasetI1path)
    values = [ ]
    times = [ ]
    for i in range(tscI1.numberValues):
        abcTime.set(tscI1.times[i])
        if tscI1.values[i] < 0 :
            values.append(float(-901.00))
            times.append(abcTime.value())
        else:
            values.append(tscI1.values[i])
            times.append(abcTime.value())
```

Currently, this is pulling all data within the time window. There are some entries at 15 minute time intervals that are cluttering my results. Therefore, I'm searching to only pull hourly values. This is my first post so I'm sorry if this isn't formatted perfectly. However, any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thank you very much in advance, and let me know if I need to provide additional information.

Comment: what sort of "database" is this?  I presume this isn't a relational/SQL based system…  as an aside, I'd suggest taking a look at the `datetime` standard module as well as the `pytz` package as they might help simplify your code

Comment: It's an Oracle PL/SQL database. Thank you for your suggestions/advice.

Comment: I'd suggest updating the question with some more detail; e.g. better tags, what database connector/package are you using (that doesn't look like DB-API usage).  ideally you'd include code that functions as a complete/executable example